# Parsing JSON To HashMap With Dynamic Keys

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am attempting to parse below json to java object. I cannnot able to parse to combined keys and values.

```
"txn": {
    "TXN_TYPE": {
      "=": "SB"
    },
    "TXN_DATE(0)": {
      "=": "0170501"
    },
    "TXN_DATE(1)": {
      "=": "0170502"
    },
    "TXN_DATE(2)": {
      "=": "0170503"
    },
    "TXN_AMT(0)": {
      "=": "10.00"
    }
    "TXN_AMT(1)": {
      "=": "20.00"
    }
    "TXN_AMT(2)": {
      "=": "30.00"
    }
}
```

i am using org.json.JSONObject to parse and iterate over it and store it in HashMap.

```
JSONObject txn= jObject.getJSONObject("txn");
if (txn!= null) {
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Iterator iter = txn.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        JSONObject valueObj = txn.getJSONObject(key);
        String value =  valueObj.getString("=");
        System.out.println("Response : Key : "+key+ " Value : "+value);
        map.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

I need to convert this as map like below format

> key : TXN_TYPE , value : SB
>
> key : TXN_DATE , value : {Key : 0, Value : 0170501} and so on
>
> key : TXN_AMT , value : {Key : 0, Value : 10.00} and so on

Please provide some suggestion.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is `computes`? Wouldn't it be better to ask `txn` for its keys?

Comment: I tried to loop json object  i have provided my code above. but i cannot able to loop over dynamic keys

Comment: Does `value : {Key : 0, Value : 0170501}` represent a string or a nested map? If it's a string, how does the "so on" look? If it's a map, how to you expect to store that in a `Map<String,String>`?

Comment: @ shmosel. it should be nested map. so i can match txn date and txn amt with keys [0,1,2...] easily.

Comment: @ shmoel. i am thinking about that only. can able to achieve by using Map<String, Object>

Comment: So you want map like this? `{TXN_TYPE=SB, TXN_DATE={0=0170501, 1=0170502, 2=0170503}, TXN_AMT={0=10.00, 1=20.00, 2=30.00}}` --- In other words, you're actually asking how to split `TXN_DATE(0)` into `TXN_DATE` and `0`? Have you tried `indexOf()` and `substring()`?

Comment: @ Andreas, Yes correct, i want map as like you mentioned, so that i can parse easily. index and substring i feel weird, is there any other way like json serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
JSONObject txn = jObject.getJSONObject("txn");
if (txn != null) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Iterator iter = txn.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iter.next();
        JSONObject valueObj = txn.getJSONObject(key);
        String value = valueObj.getString("=");
        String[] keyParams = key.split("[\\(\\)]");

        if (keyParams.length > 1) { // it means it contains index

            // checking for old map
            Map<String, String> innerMap = (Map<String, String>) map.get(keyParams[0]);

            if (innerMap == null) {
                innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
            innerMap.put(keyParams[1], value);
            map.put(keyParams[0], innerMap);
        } else {
            map.put(key, value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @ Sachin. Its working, Its really helped and Thanks a lot.