# Parsing inner int json object in android

Tags: android, json, gson, jsonobjectrequest

I have already checked other posts of Stack Overflow regarding Json data parsing but did not find the solution to parse inner Json int objects.
 I am getting the following response from a web service.

```
{
    "counter":[
    {
        "1":[
        {
            "message":"28",
            "events":0,
            "shared_files":"8"
        }
        ],
        "2":[
        {
            "message":"39",
            "events":"4",
            "shared_files":"7"
        }
        ]
        .....

        "n":[
        {
            "message":"39",
            "events":"4",
            "shared_files":"7"
        }
        ]

    }
    ]
}
```

Where "1", "2" and "n" are ids and json object size changes according to the data. I am able to parse the above response till JsonObect using following code:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = GetJson_.getArray(response, "counter");
if (jsonArray != null) {
    JsonObject object = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

and my jsonObject now looks like

```
{
    "1":[
    {
        "message":"28",
        "events":0,
        "shared_files":"8"
    }
    ],
    "2":[
    {
        "message":"39",
        "events":"4",
        "shared_files":"7"
    }
    ]
    .....

    "n":[
    {
        "message":"39",
        "events":"4",
        "shared_files":"7"
    }
    ]
}
```

But I am stuck at how to parse the JsonObject which is dynamic.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use for(...) loop only if ids come in array. Need to get corrected from backend

Answer (score 0):

hey you may use `HashMap<>` for parse dynamic key response for this check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732552/parsing-json-to-hashmap-with-dynamic-keys), other way you may use `Iterator` which i done below :

```
JSONObject jsonObject= m_jArry.getJSONObject(0);
        Log.e("ad","--------"+jsonObject.toString());

        Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();

        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            // loop to get the dynamic key
            String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next();

            // get the value of the dynamic key
            JSONObject currentDynamicValue = jsonObject.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);

            // do something here with the value...
        }
```

Hope this will helpful to you.